# Open one node and all its parents using jstree

Tags: jstree

I'm trying to use jstree and let one node and all its parent be opened when the page is opened. Here is the html code I used to test.

```
    <div id="treeTask">
       <ul>
          <li id="node_37"><a href="#">TEST1</a>
              <ul>
                  <li id="node_38"><a href="#">TEST2</a></li>
                  <li id="node_39"><a href="#">TEST3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
          <li id="node_3"><a href="#">TEST1</a>
              <ul>
                  <li id="node_4"><a href="#">TEST2</a></li>
                  <li id="node_6"><a href="#">TEST3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

And here is the call to initialize jstree and open the node.

```
 $(function () { 
        $("#treeTask").jstree();

        $("#treeTask").bind("ready.jstree", function (event, data) { 
            $("#treeTask").jstree("open_node", $("#node_4"));

            if((data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj)).length) { 
                data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).open_node(this, false); 
              }  
        }); 

  });
```

I have been manipulating the code for a while, but could not make it work. I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the built-in `_open_to` function:
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=open_to&f=_open_to%28obj%29

```
$("#treeTask").jstree().bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) { 
  data.instance._open_to('node_4');
});
```

Comment: What about this function being private or can I use it safely? In most frameworks such internal functions are subject to change in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @maddin solution, I've updated it to support any number of parent levels.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0phkc9j9/15/)

```
$("#treeTask").jstree().bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) { 
  $("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', 'node_4', function(e,d) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.parents.length; i++) {
      $("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', e.parents[i]);
    };
  });
});
```

It should be noted that if a node is selected, all its parents will be opened automatically.  This would be somewhat equivalent to the above:

```
$("#treeTask").jstree().bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) { 
  $("#treeTask").jstree('select_node', 'node_4');
});
```

Comment: You may just call `$("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', e.parents);` without `for` loop, because array of ids may be passed to `open_node` function

Comment: I cant get this to work with a class name, it only works with an id, so for example ```$("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', '.toBeOpened', function(e,d) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.parents.length; i++) {
      $("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', e.parents[i]);
    };
  });``` Wont work. Any suggestions, I have a class name on the node which needs to be open

Comment: @MohithThimmaiah, you should try [vakata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538877) - he's the author of jsTree!  And/or make absolutely sure that `.toBeOpened` is in fact the selector you want and that such an element does exists. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is an Solution for your problem:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lrz_hal/0phkc9j9/13/)

```
$("#treeTask").jstree().bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) { 
 $("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', 'node_4', function(e,d) {
     if(e.parents.length){
         $("#treeTask").jstree('open_node', e.parent);
     };
  });
});
```