# Can't open node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am working on my litle app where I use jstree. And I have some problem with programmaticall opening of node.

My tree have 5 lvls of nesting.

I have id of node and I need to open it. It belongs to last lvl of tree.

'open_node' function working with first lvl of tree but doesn't work with others. I tried to use 'load_all' function but it didn't help. What is wrong with my code?

```
$("#treeHD_classification").jstree("load_all")
$('#treeHD_classification').jstree('open_node', $("#"+selected))
```

2 attempts to open node

```
$('#treeHD_classification').on('ready.jstree', (e, data) ->  
  data.instance._open_to('j2_2_anchor')  
  $('#treeHD_classification').jstree 'open_node', 'j2_2_anchor'
```

**_open_to** - doesn't make anything
**open_node** - open's only the first lvl node

Thank you for your response.

Comment: You will have to use a private method `_open_to`, check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660403/open-one-node-and-all-its-parents-using-jstree/30538877#30538877

Comment: I read and tried what you advised me but it didn't help. This method open's only the visible node. It means I can't access node that is not on the first lvl.
The node on the second lvl can be opend only if node on the first lvl **manualy** opened.

Comment: Can you help me with my problem? @vakata

Comment: Try `$("#treeHD_classification").jstree("_open_to", 'j2_2_anchor'); `

Comment: Unfortunatelly your method doesn't open any of nodes neither on first lvl nor on any others. @NikolayErmakov

Comment: Check here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/9fpm3emf/

Comment: Thanks a lot @NikolayErmakov. You really helped me a lot. With help of your code I realised that I create my tree wrong. I made it from hash.json without parent attributes. But now I create it with parent attribute and "_open_to" method working. Thanks again. I spent a lot of time with this problem.